# Trouble running a google drive upload automatic script on a debian server

Tags: python, google-drive-api, debian, service-accounts

I have a script which automates uploading files to drive(I'm using pydrive), it authenticates using a service account and it works properly on my Windows when I execute it, but when I execute it on the debian server it shows me the following message:

> Your client does not have permission to get URL `/drive/v2/files` from this server. That’s all we know.

I don't really understand what's the difference between running the script on my laptop vs server

```
scope = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"]
gauth = GoogleAuth()
gauth.auth_method = 'service'
gauth.credentials = 
ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('client_secrets.json', 
scope)
drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)
fileList = drive.ListFile({'q': "'xxxxxxxxxxxx' in 
parents and trashed=false"}).GetList()
```

It fails when it try to list the files because it can't authenticate, but I'm using the same way to authenticate as in my laptop, which is with a service account client_secrets.json

Comment: please edit your question and include your code.   If you are using drive v2 you should consider developing this in drive v3

Comment: @DaImTo I have just edited it

Comment: Please include the full error message from google.

Comment: Is **client_secrets.json** actually a service account JSON key file? That filename is typically used with OAuth Client Secrets. Look in the file for the **type** key. It should be **service_account**.

Comment: have you tried using the [quickstart for drive](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/python) in order to test if this is an issue with your server? Also, what configuration or changes have you made from windows to the server?